# How to query a child object

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Title { get; set;} 
   //....other fields....
   //......
   //public Topics Interest { get; set; }     
   public IList<Topics> Interests { get; set; }     
}


public class Topics
{
   public int Id { get; set; }  ;
   public string Name { get; set; }  ;
   //other fields
}

public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
{
    IQueryable<EmployeeObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
}
```

My above data structure has Employee and within it has multiple interests and each interest has multiple topics

My Question is:

How would i search Employee.Interests.Name ?

```
   //i need help construct the linq....
   //the below will not work and look for something in the `EmployeeObject` rather in `Interests`
   IList<EmployeeObject> _emps = QueryableSQL().Where(x => x.Name== "Chess").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want.  Do you want items where any of their interests match a given value?

```
var query = QueryableSQL().Where(employee => 
    employee.Interests.Any(interest => interest.Name ==  "Chess"));
```

When you've been able to explain in English the query that you want the translation to LINQ will be a lot easier.

Comment: i am not sure i understand what do you mean by `When you've been able to explain in English `

Comment: LINQ queries are designed to read just like what they do, and to take things that you would do and translate them fairly directly to code.  When you say that you want all of the employees where any of their interests have a name of "Chess" the requirement maps very closely to the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Any` on the child collection to find matching `EmployeeObject`s

```
IList<EmployeeObject> _emps = 
    QueryableSQL().Where(x => x.Interests
                               .Any(i => i.Name== "Chess"))
                  .ToList();
```